# Does convergence in distribution implies imply this inequity?

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Consider a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_n$. Given that

$$X_n - \sqrt{n} c \to N(0,1)$$ in distribution ($c>0$ is a constant number bounded away from zero).

Show that for any constant $t>0$, we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(X_n>t)=1$$

To show this, I use the following proof:

$$P(X_n>t)=P(X_n-\sqrt{n} c> t-\sqrt{n})=1-P(X_n-\sqrt{n}c<t-\sqrt{n}c)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n-\sqrt{n}c<t-\sqrt{n}c) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \Phi(t-\sqrt{n}c) = \Phi(-\infty)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is the CDF of $N(0,1)$.

So, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n>t)=1$$

**However**, I am not sure whether the equation

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n-\sqrt{n}c<t-\sqrt{n}c) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \Phi(t-\sqrt{n}c)$$

is correct or not.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Obviously, one needs $c>0$. Without using the uniform convergence of the c.d.f. (which is a consequence of [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem)) : for all $t\in\Bbb R$ and $a>0$, we have $t-c\sqrt n>-a$ if $n$ is large enough, giving
$$P(X_n>t)=P\bigl(X_n-c\sqrt n>t-c\sqrt n\bigr)\ge P\bigl(X_n-c\sqrt n>-a\bigr).$$
Then, with $N\sim\cal N(0,1)$,
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}P(X_n>t)\ge P(N>-a),$$
where the right-hand side goes to $1$ as $a\to\infty$. Here it makes sense to write $X_n=c\sqrt n+N+o_{\Bbb P}(1)$ where $o_{\Bbb P}(1)$ i a random quantity converging to $0$.

Comment: @nejimban When $n$ is large enough, $t-c\sqrt{n}\to -\infty$, right? How comes we have $t-c\sqrt{n} > -a$?

Comment: It's a typo :) I meant to write $t-c\sqrt n\mathop{\color{red}<}-a$ if $n$ is large enough. Therefore $\{X_n-c\sqrt n>-a\}\subseteq\{X_n-c\sqrt n>t-c\sqrt n\}$ and the stated inequality between the two probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. If $X_n \to X$ in distribution and if the CDF of $X$ is continuous then $\sup_x|P(X_n\le x)-P(X\le x)| \to 0$. This implies that  $|P(X_n\le x_n)-P(X\le x_n)| \to 0$ for any sequence $(x_n)$.

Comment: Great answer. I have an extra question. Denote the CDF of $X_n, X$ as $F_n, F$, respectively. If $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ is uniform convergence, then the condition "$F$ is continuous" is not needed anymore, right? Because by the definition of uniform convergence, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_x |F_n(x)-F(x)|=0$.

Comment: Yes, but how can prove uniform convergence?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on geetha290krm's answer, here is why continuity of $F$ is enough to imply that convergence in distribution must be "uniform". Suppose not, so there is some $\delta>0$ and sequence $(x_n)$ such that $|P(X_n\leq x_n)-P(X\leq x_n)|>\delta$ infinitely often. By passing to a subsequence, if necessary, we can assume this holds for every $n$.

Suppose there is a subsequence $x_{n_i}\to\infty$. Then for $i$ sufficiently large, we must have $P(X_{n_i}\leq x_{n_i})<P(X\leq x_{n_i})-\delta$, since $P(X\leq x_{n_i})+\delta>1$. But also for $i$ sufficiently large we have $x_{n_i}>F^{-1}(1-\delta/2)$, contradicting convergence in distribution. A similar argument applies if some subsequence tends to $-\infty$.

The only other possibility is that some subsequence $(x_{n_i})$ has a finite limit $x$. Without loss of generality, $P(X_{n_i}\leq x_{n_i})<P(X\leq x_{n_i})-\delta$ infinitely often. But for $i$ sufficiently large we have $x_{n_i}>F^{-1}(F(x)-\delta/2)$ and so $P(X_{n_i}\leq F^{-1}(F(x)-\delta/2))<F(x)-\delta$, a contradiction.